# Implementing an auto-update mechanism

Tags: deployment

I have a question about updating applications.

If I want an application to always be up-to-date, I would probably implement a launcher that checks if it is the latest version.

What are the pro's and con's of this approach, and is there an other way to achieve this behavior in compiled programming languages (specially .NET / Java)?

How would I update the launcher? I have seen applications that can do that also.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The method of writing a launcher and checking for update is usually followed by all the applications that checks for updates. Although no necessary. Alternative to this can be a call back function which will send a "request of update" from server(the dev machine) to clients(where application is installed) when the server has a new update.

Pros of the having client to check for available update at server: Widely used
Also there are buildin classes (available for .net http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx)
Cons: Will keep checking even if update is not there (every time application is launched or timeout occurs)

Pros of callback method: no un necessary traffic (even its a very small amount still a request is made)

Cons: I dont remember of seeing any apis for such a method. So you need to implement these all by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps these links can provide some information:

- Code Project: [Application Auto-update via Online Files in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265751/Application-Auto-update-via-Online-Files-in-Csharp)
- [Writing my own Auto Updater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250175/writing-my-own-auto-updater)
- [AutoUpdate using Google Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756782/autoupdate-using-google-code)

[What is the best practice to auto upgrade MSI based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51591399/what-is-the-best-practice-to-auto-upgrade-msi-based-application/51601083#51601083)