# Create Installation Package Including SQL Silent Installation and a C# Winforms Project

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer

I want to create an installer file that includes installer file for SQL Server and a C# project so that user don't have to do it separately.

I have seen a few solutions but want to get recommendations for the best possible solution available in market.

Answer (score 0):

Some previous answers you can check:

- [List View of Common Windows Installer Deployment Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840)
- [How to create windows installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624070/how-to-create-windows-installer/49632260#49632260) (with links to non-Windows Installer tools as well)

Commercial deployment tools [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) and [Installshield](http://www.installshield.com) have some built-in support to install various prerequisites such as SQL Server Express - [a quick description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50972797/additional-setup-in-visual-studio-installer-projects/50976968#50976968). The open source and free WiX with its Burn component also allows you to install prerequisites, but you have to write XML markup code to accomplish the task. No real GUI apart from Visual Studio as editor (or another editor for that matter).

---

***Some Links***:

- [How to create a MSI file which simply copies a directory to Program Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056310/how-to-create-a-msi-file-which-simply-copies-a-directory-to-program-files/52059242#52059242)
- [Wrap C# application in .msi installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343445/wrap-c-sharp-application-in-msi-installer/50348142#50348142)
- [Application setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617506/application-setup/51618424#51618424)