# Creating an MSI in visual Studio 2013

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installshield, advanced-installer

I am looking for help with deploying an application for my company. I have tried using clickonce but it does not give the option to allow the user to select where it is to be installed. I like it because it has the built-in updater. I am looking for a solution that will work with these requirements. I dislike install-shield because the update function requires money to use.

1) Built in Updater
2) allow user to select install location
3) Creates uninstaller
4) Creates desktop and Menu Shortcuts

I really appreciate the help and through all of the things I have tried, WIX, Visual Studio Installer doesn't seem to work.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic. I wouldn't want to recommend anything anyway because you say several “doesn't seem to work” without explaining how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: I apologize for this, I was not meaning to ask for suggestions. I was rushed and I did not add what I wanted to at the bottom. I also wanted to ask if there was a more up to date tutorial on Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: 2, 3, 4 are common features WiX supports, while 1 is usually what you should write yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe check [**this answer on auto-update features**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51591399/129130). Please skim all answers - there is information about different types of deployment formats. And check the "*Roll your own*" section towards the bottom of my answer. It is "***the poor man's upgrade feature***". Further, there is [**this list of MSI tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130). Extensive links to more information.

You mention Installshield does not suit your needs due to licensing issues. You could test Advanced Installer. They have [**an upgrade feature (about)**](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/updater.html) (please read), though it is also commercial and costs money. [**Using the Updater**](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-updater.html). You can try their forum for more information: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/. I am not quite up to speed.